# Laravel routes & usernames in routes

Tags: php, laravel

What options are available to prevent users to use existing route names as an account name.

For example:
I've a route, that shows latest posts `domain.com/latest`. I also want to simplify user's profile page url's, like the following `domain.com/a_user`.

The problem occurs when a user registers with the `latest` username. It depends on route order, but I want to refuse those usernames. Is there any simple validation for this, or I should store all base routes in an array and check against it?

Comment: Another way would be using subdomain routing: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-groups. Also looks cleaner IMO :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `not_in` in conjunction with an array of route paths which you can get using `Route::getRoutes()`.
So in your case you could have something like this:

```
$routes = [];

// You need to iterate over the RouteCollection you receive here
// to be able to get the paths and add them to the routes list
foreach (Route::getRoutes() as $route)
{
    $routes[] = $route->getPath();
}

$validator = Validator::make(
    ['username' => $username],
    ['username' => 'not_in:' . implode(',', $routes)]
);
```